# tomcat server not starting in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

my tomcat server not starting with timeout 45seconds... getting following message

```
Mar 16, 2016 3:14:34 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:PosDashboard' did not find a matching property.
Mar 16, 2016 3:14:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/7.0.68
Mar 16, 2016 3:14:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Feb 8 2016 20:25:54 UTC
Mar 16, 2016 3:14:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         7.0.68.0
Mar 16, 2016 3:14:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 8.1
Mar 16, 2016 3:14:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            6.3
Mar 16, 2016 3:14:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          x86
Mar 16, 2016 3:14:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\jre
Mar 16, 2016 3:14:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.7.0_79-b15
Mar 16, 2016 3:14:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Mar 16, 2016 3:14:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         H:\Tomcat7.0
Mar 16, 2016 3:14:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         H:\Tomcat7.0
Mar 16, 2016 3:14:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=H:\Tomcat7.0
Mar 16, 2016 3:14:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=H:\Tomcat7.0
Mar 16, 2016 3:14:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=H:\Tomcat7.0\wtpwebapps
Mar 16, 2016 3:14:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=H:\Tomcat7.0\endorsed
Mar 16, 2016 3:14:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
Mar 16, 2016 3:14:34 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.2.5 using APR version 1.5.1.
Mar 16, 2016 3:14:34 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
```

I need help. Please give me some solution

[image]

this is an error.. hope u can view it

Comment: tried increasing the startup time?

Comment: Looks like still not enough 120-Seconds for startup, can you increase it ? unless you wan't get any different error then time-out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> please, increase tomcat's time-out seconds see below will help out how
>   to increase it into eclipse,
>
> by-default tomcat's time-out seconds are : 45-seconds, we can manually
>   increase it.

**do as likewise,**

[image]

Comment: @yog what's exactly issue is, can you please catch error's snap-shot and update your question so that we can more easily identify it.

Comment: ok give me some time... it takes half an hr to get that error

Comment: added snapshot... please chk